# meaning of "carve out a niche"

Tags: idioms

Can you give out the meaning of the phrase "carve out a niche"?

Full sentence:

> A string of organisations are coming together to carve out a niche for India in AI.

Answer (score 0):

**carve (out) a niche**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/niche) idiom

> To establish a role, usually by excelling in a particular
>   area. 'Our graphic designer really carved out a niche for himself with
>   that series of innovative ads.'